# 3 dots in html source code when listing folders in PHP

Tags: php, styles, directory

this is the code i wrote but i keep seeing these 3 dots before the folder name showing up:

```
<?php

$dir=new DirectoryIterator("wallpapers");


 while ($dir->valid())
  {
     $file=$dir->current();
echo $file->getFilename();
echo "<br>";
 $dir->next();
 }

?>
```

Comment: `foreach($folder as $dir){ }` maybe?

Comment: Ok. but how do i use the current folder to style it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be good to go with this

```
$dir = "/etc/php5/*";


foreach(glob($dir) as $file) 
{
    echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($file) . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Well, I figured it out by myself, but now it shows me three dots before showing the folders list. Here is the code:

Why do i see the 3 dots "." and then ".." in the html source code?
Thank you all guys!!!     
    <?php
    
    $dir=new DirectoryIterator("wallpapers");
    
    
     while ($dir->valid())
      {
         $file=$dir->current();
    echo $file->getFilename();
    echo "<br>";
     $dir->next();
     }
    
    ?>

Comment: the  . and .. folders are hidden folder. You need to build a ignored list of folder you don't wan't to see.

Comment: Try using realpath() function. It will resolve . or .. or ./ etc. Here is the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php